# How to create a nested object from the list of object by property value

Tags: javascript

I faced the real problem with parsing API and combining the response into the proper object. I've tried many solutions, but they are all failed in many ways.

If there is an answer with a solution for such question - please provide a link. Because I found many questions about how to nest, but no one how to work with shifting.

So far I have a response which looks like this:

```
[
 {path: "1.0.0"},
 {path: "1.1"},
 {path: "13"},
 {path: "2"},
 {path: "1"},
 {path: "2.0.0.1"},
 {path: "3.0.1.1"}
]
```

and I need to transform into this:

```
 [  
   {  
      path:"1",
      subCategories:[  
         {  
            path:"1.0.0",
            subcategories:[]
         },
         {  
            path:"1.1",
            subcategories:[
                           {
                             path:"1.1.0",
                             subcategories: []
                           }
           ]
         },
      ]
   },
   {  
      path:"13",
      subcategories:[]
   },
   {  
      path:"2",
      subcategories:[  
         {  
            path:"2.0.0.1",
            subcategories:[]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      path:"3.0.1.1",
      subcategories:[]
   },
]
```

The main complexity is that on server side we can hide any category and in this case child should take parent's place. Parent and child separated with a dot.

I would be very appreciated if you help me. Thank you.

Comment: why `1.0.0` instead of `1.0`, which would describe the level better ...? what have you tried?

Comment: Because category with  1.0 path  was hided on a server side. It exists but I don't receive it. So 1.0.0 is a child of 1.0 which is hided. In this way 1.0.0 should take parent's place

Comment: `1.1.0` isn't in your data, but it's in your result.

Comment: @MarkMeyer you right. My fault, I made a typo. Since I can't edit the post let's pretend that it's there ;)

Comment: I can understand why my question was downvoted. I din't provide any my solution, but I stuck with sorting logic at very beginning and there is no code to post about it. I don't care about rep point but still guys, could you be more kind for those, who just start programming or is not a native english speaker. Wish you well and have a good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach with a two step division into collecting same level items and then creating objects.

```js
function getTree(array, prefix = []) {

    function getCommon(array) {
        return array.reduce((a, b) => {
            var l = 0;
            while (a[l] === b[l] && l in a) l++;
            return a.slice(0, l);
        });
    }

    var l = array.length && getCommon(array) + 1;

    return array
        .reduce((r, a) => {
            var left = a.slice(0, l),
                right = a.slice(l),
                temp = r.find(([b]) => left.join('.') === b.slice(0, l).join('.'));

            if (temp) {
                temp[1].push(right);
            } else {
                r.push([left, [right]]);
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(([p, sub]) => {
            var path = prefix.concat(p, sub.length === 1 ? sub[0] : []);
            return {
                path: path.join('.'),
                subcategories: sub.length === 1
                    ? []
                    : getTree(sub.filter(({ length }) => length), path)
            };
        });
}

var data = [{ path: "1.0.0" }, { path: "1.1" }, { path: "1.1.0" }, { path: "13" }, { path: "2" }, { path: "1" }, { path: "2.0.0.1" }, { path: "3.0.1.1" }],
    tree = getTree(data.map(({ path }) => path.split('.')));

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This only support 2 levels, if you need to support any number of nesting you'll need a recursive solution

```js
var o = [{
    path: "1.0.0"
  },
  {
    path: "1.1"
  },
  {
    path: "13"
  },
  {
    path: "2"
  },
  {
    path: "1"
  },
  {
    path: "1.1.0"
  },
  {
    path: "2.0.0.1"
  },
  {
    path: "3.0.1.1"
  }
]

const result = o.reduce((memo, d) => {
    const key = d.path.split('.')[0]
    memo[key] ? memo[key].push(d) : memo[key] = [d]
    return memo
  }, [])
  .filter(Boolean)
  .map(items => items.map(d => d.path).sort())
  .map(items => items.reduce((memo, d) => {
    const dTransposed = {
      path: d,
      subCategories: []
    }

    if (!memo.path) {
      return dTransposed
    }
    const parent = memo.subCategories.find(c => d.startsWith(c.path))
    if (parent) {
      parent.subCategories.push(dTransposed)
    } else {
      memo.subCategories.push(dTransposed)
    }

    return memo
  }, {}))

console.log(result)
```